# Black Sholes formula

Tags: excel

I found the [**Black Sholes Option calculator**](http://www.alumni.hbs.edu/new_alumni/toolkit/tools/blackscholes.xls).

As you can see from the spreadsheet the adjusted stock price is given by `=S*EXP(-q*T)`, how can I use a function in **Excel** to lookup for the value of `q` in my spreasheet?

Answer (score 0):

`A = Se^(-qT)`, then `A/S = e^(-qT)` and `S/A = e^(qT)`.

Therefore, `ln(S/A) = qT` and so `ln(S/A)/T = q` as desired.

So your formula should be

`=ln(S/A)/T`

where `S`, `A`, and `T` are cell references to the values from which you want to compute the value of `q`.

Comment: it looks like A is adjusted stock price which is being computed from q. But I am not sure how they got the value for q , as it cannot be found from the chart.